# What is Sarvato-Bhadra-Mandala?

Tags: puja

[image]

Sarvato-Bhadra-Mandala is drawn and used in worship of many deities in hinduism. What is it actually and how is it drawn and worshipped?

Comment: No need of writing "proper reference and thanks" :)

Comment: If you hv read Tantrasara then you must be already knowing

Comment: Okay .. baumati is a publisher's name?

Comment: I think it is basumati?

Comment: @Rickross yes basumati:) sorry for the typo